# Where to put the Bearer Auth token in tosca

Tags: automation, tosca

Not able to find where to put the bearer token generated in tosca

Hi,

I tried to create a GET request in tosca which generates me a token

Now I need to provide that same token in a POST request but I dont know where to put that bearer token.

Can anyone help me with the path

Comment: The tool I am using is TOSCA Automation tool

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the generated token from GET in a buffer and use it in the next api call by providing it in the header by calling the buffer value

PS: you can use right click to translate the value to make sure you are getting correct token

Answer (score 0):

Go to Params tab in Tosca api scanner or api module. And create the header "Authorozation" in column name and put the session id in value. Make the Type as header

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).